# Erlang dynamic variable names on each iteration

Tags: erlang

Program is working now. The simplest solution was the best. The registered processes did not work. I actually was having some trouble with the call to await/2 from the base case of start/6. Turned out I was using the modified list T_T.

```
%variables
T = 10000000,       
P = 4,              
Tpart = 2500000,            
Width = 1.0 / T,
Pi = pi(T, P, [], 1), calls pi/4 and gets a list of pid

start(T, P, Tpart, Width, Pi, 1). %calls start with the Pi variable which should contain 4 Pids



    % create a list of P Pids and return it
pi(_, P, List, Count) when Count > P -> List;
pi(T, P, List, Count) ->
Pid = spawn(pi, child, []),
Count2 = Count + 1,
pi(T,P, [Pid|List], Count2).


%start iterates through a list of Pids and sends a work order to each process
start(_, P, _, _, _, StaticList, Count) when Count > P -> await(StaticList, 0.0);
start(T, P, Tpart, Width, [Head|Tail], StaticList, Count) ->   
   Head ! {work, self(), P, Count, Tpart, Width},
   Count2 = Count + 1,
   start(T,P,Tpart,Width,Tail, StaticList, Count2).


%  Collects the partial sums from child processes. Print final output
await([], Final) -> io:format(" Final Sum: ~.8f \n", [(Final * 4.0)]);
await([Pid | Rest], Final) ->
    receive
        {done, Pid, Sum} ->
        Partial = Final + Sum,
        await(Rest, Partial)
    end.
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you send the message?  Also, where is the `await/2` function defined?

Comment: Code is working now. I would love to show you the final product but SO is not letting me edit due to some error. I will update the OP once it lets me. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot name Pids directly.  You can take a process name, however, and [register](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html) it using `register/2`.  You should be careful, though, because the registered process name needs to be an atom and you could potentially [fill up the atom table](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real) if you aren't careful.

```
%Call to function
Pi = pi(T,P, [], 1, getName(1)), %list of Pids

% This is the main function that should return a list of Pid's with different names. 
pi(T, P, List, Count) when Count >= P -> List;
pi(T, P, List, Count) ->
Pid = spawn(pi, child, []), % I want to have name be: Pidx = ...
Count2 = Count + 1,
Name = getName(Count2),
register(Name,Pid),
pi(T,P, [Name|List], Count2).


%Helper method that returns an atom. I want to use this as a variable name in the main function.
getName(Count) ->
X = "Pid",
Y = integer_to_list(Count),
Name = X ++ Y,
list_to_atom(Name).
```

If you need a list of Pids, why name them at all?  You could do something like this:

```
%Call to function
Pi = pi(T,P, [], 1, getName(1)), %list of Pids

% This is the main function that should return a list of Pid's with different names. 
pi(T, P, List, Count) when Count >= P -> List;
pi(T, P, List, Count) ->
Pid = spawn(pi, child, []), % I want to have name be: Pidx = ...
Count2 = Count + 1,
pi(T,P, [Pid|List], Count2).
```

This would return a list of Pids without the need of the other helper function.

Comment: Just wanted to give you an A+ on the help. Your second code block was my gut instinct when I started coding. Then I started thinking that the spawned processes needed unique identifiers. So I really appreciate you showing me both working examples. Thanks for the nice example.